# C++ modules filesystem and iostream crashes g++

Tags: c++, g++, c++20, c++-modules

I have the following program:

```
import <iostream>;
import <filesystem>;

namespace fs = std::filesystem;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    fs::path input = "./";
    std::cout << input;
    return 0;
}
```

I compile it with (`g++` version `11.1.0`):

```
g++ -c -std=c++20 -fmodules-ts -x c++-system-header filesystem iostream
g++ -std=c++20 -fmodules-ts -o test test.cpp
```

And I receive a very cryptic message:

```
during RTL pass: expand
In file included from /usr/include/c++/11.1.0/string:55,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11.1.0/stdexcept:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11.1.0/system_error:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11.1.0/bits/fs_fwd.h:35,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11.1.0/filesystem:44,
of module /usr/include/c++/11.1.0/filesystem, imported at test.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/11.1.0/bits/basic_string.h: In static member function ‘static std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::__sv_type std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::_S_to_string_view(std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::__sv_type) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]’:
/usr/include/c++/11.1.0/bits/basic_string.h:126:16: internal compiler error: in make_decl_rtl, at varasm.c:1418
  126 |       { return __svt; }
      |                ^~~~~
0x1797368 internal_error(char const*, ...)
        ???:0
0x67f8f9 fancy_abort(char const*, int, char const*)
        ???:0
0xa1cdef expand_expr_real_1(tree_node*, rtx_def*, machine_mode, expand_modifier, rtx_def**, bool)
        ???:0
0xa26f9f store_expr(tree_node*, rtx_def*, int, bool, bool)
        ???:0
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
Please include the complete backtrace with any bug report.
See <https://bugs.archlinux.org/> for instructions.
```

What puzzles me is, that upon removing `iostream` and the `std::cout` line, the program compiles just fine.

Also if I switch from `import` to the old-fashioned `#include` the program works just fine.

Am I importing the modules wrong?
Is this a compiler bug?

Comment: This is a compiler bug because it clearly shows that this is an "internal compiler error".

Comment: Modules are still the experimental feature. From the gcc11 [changes](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-11/changes.html): Modules, Requires -fmodules-ts and some aspects are incomplete. Refer to C++ 20 Status.

Comment: Alright, I'll try the newer version...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiler support for modules is still in its early days. But if a header fails compiling as a header unit, then you can still include it instead:

```
import <iostream>;
#include <filesystem>

namespace fs = std::filesystem;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    fs::path input = "./";
    std::cout << input;
    return 0;
}
```

This is probably the best we can do for now. You might also try out precompiled headers in the meantime if your dependency list grows out of hand.

Comment: Thanks. I have also created a bug report: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=103256